# Json Key miss match issue with class property name

Tags: c#, json

```
[
 { 
   "First/Last": "This will status will be first or Last",
   "Gender": "Male"
 }
]
```

Following code is a class property:

```
[JsonProperty("First/Last")]
public string FirstLast
{
   get
   {
      return FirstLast;
   }

   set
   {
      FirstLast= value;
   }
}
```

This propery value  coming to null.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsw = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<EtherData> lst  = (List<EthenData>) jsw.Deserialize(json, typeof(List<EthenData>));
```

Can some one please address what I've mmissed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [JsonProperty("First/Last")]
    public string FirstLast
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstLast;
        }

        set
        {
            FirstLast= value;
        }
```

Above is not a valid property definition. It will cause an infinite loop in both get and set methods. Instead use auto property like  below :

```
 [JsonProperty("First/Last")]
    public string FirstLast
    {
        get; set;
       
    }
```

Or use property with backing fields if you need some extra logic in getter or setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is:

```
[
 { 
   "First/Last": "This will status will be first or Last",
   "Gender": "Male"
 }
]
```

The Type to which it should be deserialized is as under and notice the `property declaration` way:

```
public class JsonClass
{
    [JsonProperty("First/Last")]
    public string FirstLast { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

So to `deserialze` the Json to type as:

```
var deserializeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonClass>>(jsonString);
```

This returns the Json deserialized object with filled values without anyone to `null`.